# How to deploy Laravel and Vue js SPA application to Live Server?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

After looking at the laravel.log, I'm getting two errors.

1.

```
[2020-05-25 01:47:22] local.ERROR: The resource owner or authorization server denied the request.
{"exception":"[object (League\\OAuth2\\Server\\Exception\\OAuthServerException(code: 9)
```

2.

```
(InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The JWT string must have two dots at
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/highrjobsadminlte/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Parser.php:95)
```

I thought the first error might be related to the token I created being expired, but I changed the token and I'm still receiving this error. I tried googling these errors, but I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Has anyone deployed a Laravel, Vue js and Laravel Passport SPA and come across these issues when deploying to a Live Hosting Server?

Comment: Did you build your vue app by using `npm run build` before deploy ?

Comment: No I did not. So I just run that command and then upload my files? What if I've uploaded all of my files already and don't want to remove and upload everything again. Is there something I can do?

Comment: Yeah, after build your spa to minified js file then you will upload your full project again to your server otherwise you can upload only which file generated or changed after running the command

Comment: Is it only css, sass (if there are) and js files?

Comment: `I basically deployed this in the same way I did, previous Laravel and .blade apps` - that does not tell us anything, what did you do? There is more to [installing Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation) than just FTPing your files up.  Setting directory permissions is a typical problem.  Check your web server, PHP, and Laravel logs, they will all give you clues about what is happening.

Comment: #Don't Panic. Thanks, I will check Laravel log files next time. I just looked and I'm getting 2 errors. It seems like they have to do with Laravel Passport and jwt which I'm using for authentication. Should I make a new question for this?

Comment: It is the same question, right, you just have more info now?  So just edit your question and add the details.

Answer (score -1):

Execute `npm run build` before deploy. Then set the root directory on your nginx/apache2 configuration as `dist/index.html`.

Comment: Okay, sorry where is the dist folder in Laravel and Vue project?

Comment: Just a moment. Are you using Vue.js with Vue CLI or using into blade template?

Comment: Vue CLI, Vue-Router, Vuex and Laravel.

Comment: Nice. Your directory structure has laravel and vue folders into the same directory? If yes, so it is localized into Project Folder -> vue -> dist -> index.html

Comment: I think I just accidentally deleted that vue folder thinking it was a mistake, because it contained all of the files and folders that were outside of that folder, so it looked like duplicated files and folders. Is there a command that I can run to get back that vue folder? All of my Vue components are in resources/js/components and resources/js/views for View-based components.

Comment: Are you using GIT? If yes, so run the command git checkout [git commit hash]

Comment: Yeah, but I’ve made a few changes in the last day or two that I haven’t committed yet. Shoot... Why is there a vue folder inside my project that contains a complete replica of files and folders inside my project?